# bath fan, white is hot and switch doesnt disconnect

Tags: electrical

I bought a delta breeze fan .  I removed the old fan and upon labeling and disconnecting the wires the ones going to the fan connector are always hot, no matter where i move the switch, and it is the white neutral which is hot, not the black.  How did the switch ever turn off the fan in the first place?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the fan and switch boxes?

Comment: I just figured out a part of it  the whit is hot and the black is acting as a neutral.  I probed the black with the switch off and on.  there must be some reason it is reversed there are 2 switches, one for the light and the other for the fan,  the fan one is reversed

Comment: We don't have remote X-ray vision...so please get us those photos!

Comment: If the power enters the fan box and the switches are a spur, that is a **switch loop** and it is *normal* for the white to be used as always-hot.   There is no neutral at all: the other wires are switched-hot/light switched-hot/fan.   Convention is to use the white wire for always-hot so it will be immediately obvious it's not a neutral.